# Mule Logger is not working

Tags: logging, mule

my project is maven project.I have create mule flow config and **log4j.properties** inside **src/main/app**. this is how i call logger in the flow :

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"  message="#[payload]" />
```

I'm using STS ide and start project application by deploy on tomcat server. 
When i have running into the flow other component work well but don't have any log show.

Do I need to config anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ship the Log4J library with your application. Did you do so?

Comment: I have it and all lib by .pom download from this repository url : http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your log4j.properties file in src/main/resources  .

This might help.